Workflow for ZOHO CRM
I am new in ZOHO CRM and I am learning this right now, I don't know much about it.
If I create a deal and it is in the same stage, then after 3 days a mail notification has to be sent and a task has to be created. Tell me the workflow for it.
I created a follow up date field but i am unable to create workflow for this .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you want to trigger the email and create a task based on your "Follow -up" Date  Field,then you these steps :-

Navigate to the zoho crm "Setting" Icon.Under "Automation"
tab Click on Workflow Rules.

Click on "Create Rule" button .Select Module name in whch you
want to configure the workflow rule,enter rule name,description
then click on Next Button.

Select "Date/Time field" Event,then select "Follow-Up"
field,select "Custom" in execution date field then enter 3 and
select "days after" click on done ,then select execution
time,Recur value.

Add filter based on "stage " field .Example: if stage is
"Qualified".

Select Intsant Action "Email Notifiation" and Create Task.


please check this Screenshot for your reference:-Workflow based on Follow-up Date field

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

ok will remember this point in future.
